# QLocale detects system language incorrectly on Windows with language pack installed

Tags: windows, qt, localization, internationalization, qlocale

I am attempting to detect current system language with `QLocale`:

```
QLocale::Language sysLangId = QLocale::system().language();
```

However, it's not working correctly. I'm on Russian Windows 7 with English language pack applied, but `language()` returns Russian instead of English. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found 2 ways to solve my problem. The Qt way is to use `QLocale::system().uiLanguages()`.
On my system it returns a list with a single item "en-US". The problem with that is I need a language name, like "english", so I'd have to add a map for converting language code to language name. It's no big deal, but I've decided to use WinAPI:

```
QString sysLangName;
const LANGID langId = GetUserDefaultUILanguage();
WCHAR langName[1000] = {0};
if (GetLocaleInfoW(MAKELCID(langId, SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, langName, sizeof langName / sizeof langName[0] - 1) != 0)
    sysLangName = QString::fromWcharArray(langName);
```

Comment: Is there any WinAPI to give codes like en_US instead of full language name? I am reluctant to use `QLocale::system().uiLanguages()`, as its documentation says that it returns a list of locale names and in that list, the first item is the most preferred one. This preferred one may not be the current ui language (not sure).

Answer (score 7):

When I was working on Localization in Qt, I used

```
QString locale = QLocale::system().name();
```

When I tested getting the locale, I found it was dependent on the Format in the Region and Language settings:

Control Panel > Region and Language > Format

[image: Windows Region and Language Format Setting (german)]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Understood. Indeed, that's exactly what QLocale::system() indicates, and it makes sense now that I think about it. But how can I detect system UI language?

Comment: It is probably one of the other settings in Region and Language, like the Location, or the Keyboard, or the Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs.  (I would try the last one first).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved with this code.

```
QString local =  QLocale::languageToString(QLocale::system().language());
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the language name you can simply use `QLocale::languageToString(QLocale::system().language());` or maybe `QLocale::system().nativeLanguageName();` but the real problem is as you mentioned that the QLocale::system() does not always match the actual system locale on windows. This can be observed if you change the locale during program execution. In this case the QLocale::system() does not get up-to-date and returns the old value. Here is a workaround I used in Qt5:

```
class WinEventFilter : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
public:     
    bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
    {
        if (((MSG*)message)->message == WM_WININICHANGE )
        {
            // Workaround - in Qt5 the system locale is not up to date and we have to manually update it.
#ifdef _DEBUG
            QLibrary lib("Qt5Cored.dll");
#else
            QLibrary lib("Qt5Core.dll");
#endif
            void (* func)() = lib.resolve("?updateSystemPrivate@QLocalePrivate@@SAXXZ");
            if (func)
                func();
            else
                qDebug()<<"! Unable to resolve updateSystemPrivate()";
            // Workaround end

            qDebug()<<"WM_WININICHANGE"<<QLocale::languageToString(QLocale::system().language());
        }

        return false;
    }    
};
```

and my application class constructor looks like this:

```
MyApplication::MyApplication( int & argc, char ** argv ) 
: QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    WinEventFilter *pFilter = new WinEventFilter(this);
    installNativeEventFilter(m_pEventFilter);
}
```

Hope this helps.